# How do I disassemble a 17 inch Proview 700P Monitor?

Tags: display

I dug out this old monitor in order to replace some bad capacitor (had it in high school, it went bad and I stored it in my closet). The problem is that I am having a hard time disassembling it to get to the boards.
[image: Manufacturing Information]
[image: Front of Monitor]
[image: Back of Monitor]

There were only 4 screws along the bottom of the back of the monitor, removing them allow me to pull out the front panel around the screen. I was also able to remove the stand by removing the large screw on the back of the monitor

[image: first set of screws]
[image: stand removed]

That gave me access to additional screws along the sides which allowed me to pull the back from the screen, however it appears that the power supply and that video circuit board are enclosed in a shield attacked to the back panel of the monitor.

[image: Side screws]
[image: I don't know what to do next.]

There are 3 sets of cables running from this shielded box to the screen (which is also heavily shielded, this monitor is way too heavy for a 17 inch) and I cant seem to be able to pull them out. The VGA cable is encased partially in the back panel and runs into the shielded box (it isn't a separate cable, it is part of the monitor), so it is keeping this whole thing together.

Does anyone know if there is a tutorial specific to disassembling this model or does anyone have any experience with doing it?

I found a couple of useful videos. Apparently Proview does market it's products under different brands. [This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUqc278eDwY) appears to depict my monitor, but offers me no help. [This other video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rkYJS2KhnTc) gives instructions on how to disable a KDS model 900P monitor. The construction of that monitor leads me to believe that it was constructed by Proview as a successor to the monitor I have, only under a different brand name. The connectors in my monitor are slightly different.

Comment: Disconnecting the cables is less important than gaining access to the power supply PCB, which will be under the shield attached to the back fascia. You need to find some way to remove that shield, which should both expose the cap(s) you need to replace, and expose cable connectors which can be unplugged. In your last picture it looks like the shield mounts to the fascia by means of screws; is that not so? (The quality makes it hard to tell.)

Comment: @AaronMiller yeah, sorry about the quality. There are 4 screws that mount that shielded box to the backing of the monitor, however, even with those screws removed, I can remove the move entirely because the vga cable is molded into the back (see the 5th picture). Also, there isn't much room for me to work in there. My hands are rather large. :S

Comment: I can't make out what you mean, but I'll take your word for it. There is probably a way to mobilize that cable; it may involve carefully removing some plastic or bending some metal, but it should be feasible to do. In order to replace the caps, you'll need to get the PCB completely free of the enclosure anyway, so your options would seem to reduce at this point to finding some way of getting the cables loose, or giving up on the project entirely.

Comment: @AaronMiller you were right, I was able to slide that weird piece that held the cable to the back out of place.

Comment: I don't know how helpful this will be, but http://www.scribd.com/doc/154447547/proview-700p#download has an exploded diagram for the monitor's casing. You will need to register an account to view it though. It is on page 15.

Comment: @Nil Glad to be of help.